# Using an API Feed with Magento

Tags: api

I am new to stackexchange.

Apologies if I am not providing enough information but just wondered if anyone can help.

I am looking at moving my website over to the magento platform as I have been offered an API Feed by my drop shipping supplier.

They have said that I can pull all info from their feed including product info, images, prices, stock ect.

Would anyone know if this is possible? and if so how easy it is?

I look forward to hearing from you.

Bubble

Answer (score 0):

The drop shipping provider has given you an API for their system. You would then need to take the output which they have provided you with and parse that into a format that can be imported by the Magento import system.

Alternatively, you could write a custom import script which would take the format that is provided and automatically create the required products in Magento.

You might want to try asking them if they have an existing module for Magento that would take the burden of this task away.